# ahk hotkey profiles

Tags: excel, scripting, autohotkey, key-bindings, vba

Here is my working code in case this helps anybody else!

```
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
#SingleInstance FORCE

GUI, Add, Radio, vInventoryCompare, Compare Inventories
GUI, Add, Radio, vProductionSheet, Production Spreadsheet Stuff
GUI, Add, Radio, vInventorySheet, Inventory Sheet Stuff
GUI, Add, Radio, vStop, Disable Hotkeys
GUI, Add, Button, default xm, Set  ; xm puts it at the bottom left corner.
GUI, Show

ButtonSet:
GUI, Submit, NoHide
Return




Insert:: ; paste values
send, {alt}hvv
return

; ----------------------------------

Home::
If InventoryCompare = 1 ; font size up 3 times
{
Send, {enter}{up}
Loop 3
{
Send, {alt}hfg
}
return
}
Else If ProductionSheet = 1 ; Recheck
{
Send, {enter}{up}
Send, {alt}hfc{down 7}{right 3}{enter}
Send, {F2}{left 5}
Send, R-{enter}{up}
return
}
Else If Stop = 1
{
send {Home}
Return
}
Return

; ----------------------------------

End::
If InventoryCompare = 1 ; autocounter for bcg
{
Sendraw, =SUMIF($A$8:$A$38,A3,$F$8:$F$38)
send {enter}
return
}
Else If ProductionSheet = 1 ; discard
{
Send, D{enter}{up}
Send, ^b
return
}
Else If InventorySheet = 1 ; write ok+ and tab
{
send {tab}
Sendraw, ok+
send {tab}
return
}
Else If Stop = 1
{
send {end}
Return
}
Return

; ----------------------------------

PgUp::
If InventoryCompare = 1 ; green bg with white text
{
Send, {alt}hh{down 6}{right 5}{enter} ; bg green
Send, {alt}hfc{down}{left 4}{enter} ; font white
return
}
Else If ProductionSheet = 1 ; ok+ coloring
{
Send, {enter}{up}
Send, {alt}hfc{down 7}{right}{enter}
return
}
Else If InventorySheet = 1 ; write ok and tab
{
send {tab}
Sendraw, ok
send {tab}
return
}
Else If Stop = 1
{
send {PgUp}
Return
}
Return

; ----------------------------------

PgDn:: 
If  InventoryCompare = 1 ; red bg with white text
{
Send, {alt}hh{down 6}{right}{enter} ; bg red
Send, {alt}hfc{down}{left 4}{enter} ; font white
return
}
Else If ProductionSheet = 1 ; ok- coloring
{
Send, {enter}{up}
Send, {alt}hfc{down 7}{left 3}{enter}
return
}
Else If InventorySheet = 1 ; write ok- and tab
{
send {tab}
Sendraw, ok-
send {tab}
return
}
Else If Stop = 1
{
send {PgDn}
Return
}
Return

; ----------------------------------

PrintScreen::
If InventoryCompare = 1 ; Break merged top cell of old inventories
{
send {F2} ; enter cell
sleep 200
send +{left 50} ; select name
sleep 200
send ^x ; cut name
sleep 200
send {enter}{up} ; reselect cell
sleep 200
send {alt}hmu ; break merged cells
sleep 200
send {down}{f2}^v{enter} ; paste name
return
}
Else If Stop = 1
{
send {PrintScreen}
Return
}
Return


GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

Old question:
I have 3 sets of keybind macros that I would like to consolidate into a single script using a GUI with radio buttons (or some other means) to select which set of hotkeys are currently active.  Unfortunately I keep getting "Duplicate Hotkey" errors (on the End key if that tells you anything) every time I run the script.

I've been scouring the net trying to find somebody attempting the same thing but I am coming up with nothing. Am I on the right track?  Is it even possible?

Thanks for your time!

```
GUI, Add, Radio, vInventoryCompare, Compare Inventories
GUI, Add, Radio, vProductionSheet, Production Spreadsheet Stuff
GUI, Add, Radio, vInventorySheet, Inventory Sheet Stuff
GUI, Add, Radio, vDisable, Disable hotkeys
GUI, Show

GuiClose:
ExitApp

IF ErrorLevel
ExitApp

Insert:: ; paste values
send, {alt}hvv
return

IF %vInventoryCompare% = 1
{
End:: ; autocounter for bcg
Sendraw, =SUMIF($A$8:$A$38,A3,$F$8:$F$38)
send {enter}
return

Home:: ; font size up 3 times
Send, {enter}{up}
Loop 3
{
Send, {alt}hfg
}
return

PgUp:: ; green bg with white text
Send, {alt}hh{down 6}{right 5}{enter} ; bg green
Send, {alt}hfc{down}{left 4}{enter} ; font white
return

PgDn:: ; red bg with white text
Send, {alt}hh{down 6}{right}{enter} ; bg red
Send, {alt}hfc{down}{left 4}{enter} ; font white
return

PrintScreen:: ; Break merged top cell of old inventories
send {F2} ; enter cell
sleep 200
send +{left 50} ; select name
sleep 200
send ^x ; cut name
sleep 200
send {enter}{up} ; reselect cell
sleep 200
send {alt}hmu ; break merged cells
sleep 200
send {down}{f2}^v{enter} ; paste name
return

}

IF %vProductionSheet% = 1
{
End:: ; discard
Send, D{enter}{up}
Send, ^b
return

Home:: ; Recheck
Send, {enter}{up}
Send, {alt}hfc{down 7}{right 3}{enter}
Send, {F2}{left 5}
Send, R-{enter}{up}
return

PgUp:: ; ok plus coloring
Send, {enter}{up}
Send, {alt}hfc{down 7}{right}{enter}
return

PgDn:: ; ok minus coloring
Send, {enter}{up}
Send, {alt}hfc{down 7}{left 3}{enter}
return
}

IF %vInventorySheet% = 1
{
End::
send {tab}
Sendraw, ok+
send {tab}
return

PgUp::
send {tab}
Sendraw, ok
send {tab}
return

PgDn::
send {tab}
Sendraw, ok-
send {tab}
return
}

IF %vDisable% = 1
{
}
```

Comment: Do you know what duplicate means?

Comment: That's nice of you.  Yes, I was hoping those IF statements would solve that.  I don't see why duplicates should be an issue if I can make all but one inactive at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define the same hotkey multiple times in a naive way you are doing, the only way to have them is using [#IfWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).

I suggest instead of making multiple hotkeys and multiple if statements, make one hotkey and put all those if statements into it.

```
hotkey::
    if(statement)
    {
        do this;
    }
    else if(statement)
    {
        do that;
    }
    else...
return
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry you're having a bad day.

Comment: @user1988168 I am not actually :), i was just pointing the obvious and hoping you would learn yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have settled on an answer, but if you use AutoHotKey_L you can use `#IF`.
`#IF` works like `#IfWindowActive`, but then with regular if statements.
Here you could create a script like:

```
#IF (vInventoryCompare = 1)
    Home::
        Send....
        .
        .
    Return
#IF (vProductionSheet = 1)
    Home::
        Send....
        .
        .
    Return
#IF
```

P.s. if you want to send OK+, you can do it with SendRaw, but you can also do this with a regular Send. Here you would write it: Send, OK+=
The + shifts the next character. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> is <kbd>+</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your input.  I'll keep that in mind for the future!